# Rails Multiple `if` statements not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have multiple `if` statements.

```
  <% if offer.merchant == 'webgains' %>
    <a href="<%= offer.url %>&clickref=<%= current_user.id %>" target="_blank">
  <% else %>
    <a href="<%= offer.url %>" target="_blank">
  <% end %>

  <% if offer.merchant == 'rakuten' %>
    <h1>WOOP</h1>
  <% else %>
    <h1>FAIL</h1>
  <% end %>

  <% if offer.merchant == 'cj' %>
    <a href="<%= offer.url %>?sid=<%= current_user.id %>" target="_blank">
  <% else %>
    <a href="<%= offer.url %>" target="_blank">
  <% end %>

  <% if offer.merchant == 'aw' %>
    <a href="<%= offer.url %>&clickref=<%= current_user.id %>" target="_blank">
  <% else %>
    <a href="<%= offer.url %>" target="_blank">
  <% end %>
```

Is there any way to consolidate them to cleaner code as well as making them work smoothly?

Comment: You should put your conditional logic into your controller, assign the result to a variable, and then refer to that variable in your view. Don't fill a view with tests, do it all beforehand. Ruby and ERB are not PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code can be simplified into a single helper function like so in your helper file:

```
def merchant_link(merchant, url, user_id)
  case merchant
  when "webgains", "aw"
    "<a href=\"#{url}&clickref=#{user_id}\" target=\"_blank\">".html_safe
  when "cj"
    "<a href=\"#{url}?sid=#{user_id}\" target=\"_blank\">".html_safe
  when "rakuten"
    "<h1>WOOP</h1>".html_safe
  else
    "<h1>FAIL</h1>".html_safe
  end
end
```

And then call the helper function in your view:

```
<%= merchant_link(offer.merchant, offer.url, current_user.id) %>
```

You'll need to refactor your logic because there are ambiguities in your if else statement.

This might not be the best solution(I would use `link_to` to do the complete `<a>` block instead of only returning the open tag).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `if`..`elsif`..`else`..`end` or `case`..`when`..`end` since your conditions are on the same variable:

```
<% if offer.merchant == 'webgains' or offer.merchant == 'aw' %>
  <a href="<%= offer.url %>&clickref=<%= current_user.id %>" target="_blank">

<% elsif offer.merchant == 'rakuten' %>
  <h1>WOOP</h1>

<% elsif offer.merchant == 'cj' %>
  <a href="<%= offer.url %>?sid=<%= current_user.id %>" target="_blank">

<% else %>
  <h1>FAIL</h1>
  <a href="<%= offer.url %>" target="_blank">
<% end %>
```

Read "[Ruby if...else, case, unless](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm)" for more about conditional statements.